# GCP's PubSub yields "no available instance" error with scheduled tasks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to setup a scheduled task to run every hour and say send emails. In a Firebase project, I've setup a function with `.schedule('every 60 minutes')` and can see it successfully in the GCP portal as well. Recently, this error started to show up in the logs: `"The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability"` tied to this scheduled function.

There are plenty of conversations online that I saw tied to "no available instance" and mainly due to traffic spikes etc.. But for a scheduled task, what can I do to avoid this? My main goal is to not have to worry if I have 3 tasks to run the next hour or 300. I want to auto-scale and do the magic that it does. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, the error is tagged Warning for severity so according to the docs this means it is reaching the `max-instances` threshold. But I have it set very high and the amount of tasks I am scheduling are way below this max...
Also does it mean that the task will retry next when an instance is available?

Comment: I would investigate why the instance is not available. Does it come to life respecting Cloud Functions constrains and requirements? How much dependencies do you load at boot? Do you cache them? Etc...

Comment: some of the I have no Max Instance setting. So Min instances = 0 and Max is not set. I just want those to wake up (as long as they need) and run as many as I need and as high as possible. 
some I do have max of say 5, but what I want there is no more than 5 running at a time but still process all tasks.
is that possible do you know?
I am not sure what caching you are referring to

Comment: Answer is not easy, the use case is not very clear. I would recommend to review the docs about configuring functions options: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring

Comment: so the basic use case is to create a document onCreate trigger function (default settings) and drop a few hundred documents at once. That onCreate function will trigger the no-available-instance error :(

Comment: @GeneRator, did you ever figure this out? I have a function that runs every night to do a backup using the .schedule() same as you do. Every night it throws this error, but still manages to run (I'm guessing do to GCP promise to deliver at-least-one execution). What I don't get is why it started throwing this error, I will never need more than one instance and a scheduled function should be OK with a cold start?

Comment: I have not found an exact solution but I think one of the explanations I've seen online is that this error was always there but only recently google has been making it show up in our logs. What I am worried about is then this error has a higher severity than just warning. I just can't tell if this code ran or actually never executed..